# URL rewrite not working in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have  problem i am using htaccess for add index.php and convert url also.

index.php working perfect but url is not converting.

Given url : http://example.com/allmodels/Samsung-mobiles_80

I want to convert into http://example.com/allmodels?st=Samsung-mobiles_80

I have used following syntax.

1:

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$1
        RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ allmodels?st=$1 [NC,L]
```

2:

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ allmodels?st=$1 [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$1
```

3:

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ allmodels?st=$1 [NC]
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$1
```

I have try many syntax but all that not working for me.

I got error 404 page not found.

Comment: Reorder your rules, put the last rule above your first rule.

Comment: I have done it already but i got same problem

Comment: Please update the codes in question to reflect your latest changes.

Comment: Won't you need a slash in front of the 'allmodels' part?

Comment: I get string after allmodels/ so i am using slash.